# How do I separate 2 drinking glasses that are stuck?

Tags: kitchen, glass

So, I have two glasses that are stuck together. **How can I separate them without damaging them?**

I have already tried this but it didn't work, as the glasses are really thick:

> First, drizzling some vegetable oil or dish soap in between the two drinking glasses and wiggling gently to see if they'll pop apart.

And this:

> Hot water and ice water. Submerge the bottom glass or bowl in very hot
>    (but not boiling) water. Fill the uppermost glass or bowl with ice
>    water. Presto! The simultaneous expansion and contraction of the
>    layers should unstick even the most stubborn glassware.

[Found here](http://lifehacker.com/5466773/how-to-separate-stuck-drinking-glasses)

Comment: @esq I have an idea that might work depending how they are stuck together. Can you better describe how they are stuck together? In particular, is one inside of the other and stuck like stacked buckets or is it one acting a lid to the other. As well were they wet when stuck together or does either contain fluids inside of one of them (very important)?

Comment: yes they are stacked like buckets. [[image](http://thingiverse-production.s3.amazonaws.com/renders/aa/54/e0/b7/b1/Drinking_glass_preview_featured.jpg)] something like this and the problem is the edges are making it hard. they were dry when stuck together. they are normal drinking glasses and do not contain any fluid other than the one i put in

Comment: Tip for you: if you want to make sure someone see your response to their comments, you can write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure that @CRSouser saw your response to their comment.

Comment: I ran into this while bartending pretty frequently. I just submerged both glasses in ice water for a couple of minutes in the beer trough. Some one called me a derogatory term for a chemist.. I took it as a compliment

Comment: A little twisting motion could help to break the seal on the cups, just be careful not to break the glass.

Comment: By the way I failed and got rid of the glasses and can not try if any of these methods work anymore for my case..

Comment: Take a back massager to it on low.

Comment: I got mine unstucked by filling the outer glass (only) with water and keep my fingers around the gap to not let air out, then blowing inside the gap. This creates a pressure difference and made them come appart easly. Make sure to not blow too hard from the start to avoid breaking the bottom of the glass.

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1:**

Modification on what you have tried. Instead of pouring ice water, Use ice cubes or crushed ice on the top glass. Make sure entire glass is filled up. Also use candle or cigarette lighter to heat up instead of hot water for the bottom glass, Supply heat on the brim of the bottom glass. Heating will help the glass molecules to expand and rapid cooling by ice cubes helps the molucules to contract. This is more effective comparatively.

**Method 2:**

Spray water-displacing spray, WD 40 on the brim on the bottom glass and twist them.

**Method 3:**

Stick duct tape on the full upper outside circumference(around the brim) of the both the glasses in opposite direction with one another. Make sure tapes not sticking with the other glass and Cut the tape leaving length for you to pull. Pull them apart. Do it slowly. Better to pull over the cushion or bed if it is glass.

You can also add drops of oil or petroleum jelly as lubrication on the brim of the bottom glass before pulling apart.

**TIPS:**

Do not stack with water or moisture, dry them before stacking.

Use a paper nakpin between one another while stacking

Comment: Please post separate answers for each method. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Blasts of compressed air, directed from a "blow nozzle" at the edge of the outer glass,
will sometimes allow enough pressure into the outer glass to force the inner glass out.
Face and hand protection -- goggles and gloves -- are recommended in case of possible
breakage.  If the air compressor has an adjustable pressure regulator, begin with low
pressure, using short bursts of air: pfft -- pfft -- pfft -- pfft --  If no success, 
increase the pressure a bit and try again.

If there is no regulator adjustment, as on some industrial house air systems, start with
the blow nozzle a foot or two away from the edge, attempting to keep the air jet aimed
only toward the outer glass.

(Works well for jammed 5-gallon buckets, and no danger of broken glass.)

Comment: This is how large fiberglass parts (hoods, fenders) are removed from molds as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine unstucked by filling the outer glass (only) with water and keep my fingers around the gap to not let air out, then blowing inside the gap. This creates a pressure difference and made them come appart easly. Make sure to not blow too hard from the start to avoid breaking the bottom of the glass.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that:

Running hot tap over the outer glass at the point where the inner glass is stuck. while gently working the inner glass back and forth, will cause the inner glass to loosen and it will eventually come loose. This usually takes a few minutes and it's advisable to wear gloves while doing this in case the inner glass comes loose too quickly and you drop it.

The same effect can also be achieved if you lower the outer glass into a pot or a pan of warm to hot water (although not so hot that it causes the glass to break) waiting several minutes and then attempting to work the outer glass free. Again gloves should be used as if you grip the inner glass too firmly, your risk breaking it.

Answer (score -1):

Try holding a vibrating object such as an electric shaver (or perhaps even toothbrush) to the outer glass while pulling gently.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! This sounds like a good idea, but I don't think it's really clear. Can you add some more detail and (if possible) some pictures. Thanks!

Comment: Explaining why it would work is also a good idea here.